# WebAPI Read Multipart twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, multipartform-data

I have an `OwinApplication` which hosts one or several `ApiController`'s. I also have plugged in an `ActionFilterAttribute` which will validate the request before it hits the `Controller`

One of my methods inside this controller expecteds the request as Multipart. This is read by an extension method

```
Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
```

The issue I'm facing is when I use this method twice, in the `ActionFilterAttribute` and in the `Controller`. When read the second time, an exception will be thrown `Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream`

I do think this is due to the stream never being resetted to Position 0, but as I'm using the extension method I do not have control over the reading of this stream..

Any suggestions? Do I need to implement the reading of the multipart message my self?

Cheers!

Comment: You could always read once and make a local copy in the `Items` container so that subsequent reads are from the copy.

Comment: How would you pass this copy to the controller? Or am I missing something?

Comment: "in the ActionFilterAttribute and in the Controller" are you certain that you need to call this method in the filter and controller? is it being used for validation and..?

Comment: Its being used for validation and whatever the webapi method needs to do. The thing is that I will build this as a framework. Therefore I have controller over what happends in the `ActionFilterAttribute`, but not always in the WebApi Controller.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen: in the `Items` container, as I said. I am sure you know that one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx